# How to single search to identify a point value?

Tags: javascript

I've developed a Scrabbler code, but when I am trying to identify a specific value I get an error.

I've tried multiple ways but I am stuck on printing the specific point value.

```js
const oldScoreKey = {
  1: ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'L', 'N', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
  2: ['D', 'G'],
  3: ['B', 'C', 'M', 'P'],
  4: ['F', 'H', 'V', 'W', 'Y'],
  5: ['K'],
  8: ['J', 'X'],
  10: ['Q', 'Z']
};


function transform(oldScoreKey) {
  const newScoreKey = {};
  for (const [letterValue, letterArr] of Object.entries(oldScoreKey)) {
    for (const letter of letterArr) {
      newScoreKey[letter.toLowerCase()] = letterValue;
    }
  }
  return newScoreKey;
}

console.log(transform(oldScoreKey));

console.log("Scrabble scoring values for");
console.log("letter z:", newScoreKey.z);
```

the output should be:
letter a: 1,

I've tried `console.log("letter a:", newScoreKey.a);` is wrong. I've gotten an error

Comment: You don't have access to `newScoreKey` outside of function, you need to assign return value of function to some variable and than use it however you want

Answer (score 0):

You need a global variable, otherwise you can no access `newScoreKey`.

```js
const oldScoreKey = {
  1: ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'L', 'N', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
  2: ['D', 'G'],
  3: ['B', 'C', 'M', 'P'],
  4: ['F', 'H', 'V', 'W', 'Y'],
  5: ['K'],
  8: ['J', 'X'],
  10: ['Q', 'Z']
};

const newScoreKey = {};

function transform(oldScoreKey) {
  for (const [letterValue, letterArr] of Object.entries(oldScoreKey)) {
    for (const letter of letterArr) {
      newScoreKey[letter.toLowerCase()] = letterValue;
    }
  }
  return newScoreKey;
}


console.log("Scrabble scoring values for");
console.log("letter z:", newScoreKey.z);

console.log(transform(oldScoreKey));
```

Answer (score 0):

`newScoreKey` is a local variable which is only available inside the function `transform`. You need to store the result of the function in a global variable.

```js
const oldScoreKey = {
  1: ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'L', 'N', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
  2: ['D', 'G'],
  3: ['B', 'C', 'M', 'P'],
  4: ['F', 'H', 'V', 'W', 'Y'],
  5: ['K'],
  8: ['J', 'X'],
  10: ['Q', 'Z']
};


function transform(oldScoreKey) {
  const newScoreKey = {};
  for (const [letterValue, letterArr] of Object.entries(oldScoreKey)) {
    for (const letter of letterArr) {
      newScoreKey[letter.toLowerCase()] = letterValue;
    }
  }
  return newScoreKey;
}

const newScoreKey = transform(oldScoreKey)
console.log("Scrabble scoring values for");
console.log("letter z:", newScoreKey.z);
```

Comment: thank you, i was having a simple variable/Reference error.